# How can I force a request type (HttpRequestService::isCpRequest vs. HttpRequestService::isSiteRequest)?

Tags: plugin-development, url, request

Is there a way to force a request type (`HttpRequestService::isCpRequest` vs. `HttpRequestService::isSiteRequest`)?

In my case I'm generating some indexing data on `entries.onSaveEntry`. I'm trying to use some `UrlHelper` methods, but the resulting urls are wrong, since it thinks it is a cp request.

I have to do something like this load templates:

```
craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::Site);
```

Is there any way to do something similar for request type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `setRequestType()` method or the like, no. The [HttpRequestService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#isCpRequest-detail) will consider any request with the `cpTrigger` in its URL a control panel request, and I don't see any easy way around that.

It's a bit convoluted, but what you could do is to wrap whatever code you're currently executing in your `entries.onSaveEntry` in a controller action method, and then use [Guzzle](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/docs.html) in your `onSaveEntry` event handler to trigger a *site* request (i.e. a request *without* the `cpTrigger` in the URL) to that action.

Here's how your controller action could look:

```
<?
namespace Craft;

class MyPluginController extends BaseController
{

    protected $allowAnonymous = ['actionGenerateIndex'];

    public function actionGenerateIndex ()
    {

        // Get entry (based on a ?entryId URL parameter
        $entryId = craft()->request->getParam('entryId');
        $entry = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry, [
            'id' => $entryId,
        ])->first();

        // ...your code to generate the index data here

    }
}
```

Here's how you could fire off a request to this action using Guzzle, stripping the `cpTrigger` from the action URL to make sure Craft treats the action as a site request:

```
craft()->on('entries.onSaveEntry', function (Event $e) {

    // Get entry
    $entry = $e->params['entry'];

    // Get action URL, strip the `cpTrigger` segment
    $actionUrl = UrlHelper::getActionUrl('myPlugin/generateIndex', [
        'entryId' => $entry->id,
    ]);
    $actionUrl = str_replace(craft()->config->get('cpTrigger').'/', '', $actionUrl);

    // Request action
    $client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();
    $request = $client->get($actionUrl, [], [
      'headers' => [
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
      ],
    ]);
    $request->send();

});
```

Comment: Thanks @matsmikkel! Yep, a bit icky, but if I really needed to, your solution is a good one. I suppose I should make a FR for forcing the request type.